# What are the differences between the John Carter (2012) movie and the novel A Princess of Mars?

Tags: barsoom, john-carter

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Carter_%28film%29#Source_material_and_film_plot)

> The film is largely based on *A Princess of Mars*, the first novel to feature the hero John Carter.

What are the plot differences between the two of them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. He didn't learn the Barsoomian language via a potion, he learned over the period of a couple of days.
2. He died on earth and was magically transported to Mars.  There was never a Talisman.
3. There was no super weapon.
4. Woola was a faithful companion, but wasn't that fast.
5. He could read Martian minds in the book; I think that is how he knew the Chief had a secret daughter and the daughter never knew her dad for her safety.
6. Dejah Thoris, was unable to marry John Carter, because she had accepted the bad Jeddak's proposal and she could not go back on her word even if John Carter killed the bad Jeddak.
7. There were no shape shifter super bad guys that I can remember.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie yet, but based on [another question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12864/what-are-the-holy-therns-in-john-carter) it seems that they've introduced the Holy Thern's (referred to above as 'shape shifter bad guys') earlier than ERB did in the books.

Comment: Yes, the Therns are the main part of the second book. They mention the Thern in first book but nothing more than 2 or 3 lines.

Comment: @DannyBGood Re. 4: Woola could travel very fast as was seen in the third book 'warlord of Mars' when John Carter gives him a message to take back to Helium from the city of Okar. Also John Carter didn't die, but had an out of body experience whilst under the influence of some unnamed powerful drug administered by an old indian lady who we never meet because she dies during his initial ten years on Barsoom.

Comment: also Tars Tarkas daughter, Sola tells John Carter about Tars Tarkas being her father nothing to do with his mind reading abilities

Comment: Reading Princess of Mars as we speak - there is no drug from an Indian lady - his body seemed to die from a poison gas in the cave....???

Comment: Also the surface of Mars was covered in a yellowish moss, not just plain dirt, which is why many animals did not have (nor need) hooves.

Comment: And he did not kill the Thark with one punch as in the movie - he just knocked him senseless.

Comment: @ajotr "the thing it (the body of the indian lady)leaned over was a small charcoal burner upon which rested a round copper vessel containing a small quantity of greenish powder" this to me is the remains of some(yes in gas form) powerful drug .

Comment: @ajotr "now for the first time i realised that my blow on the occasion of my first battle in the audience chamber had resulted in the death of my adversary" he did kill the thark with one blow in both the film and the book.

Comment: I would also add that honor was an extremely important part of the book and a major part of John Carter's character (as well as Dejah Thoris').  He loved and was loyal to her from the start.  In the book, Dejah Thoris would NEVER have turned down Sab Than, no matter how vile he was, because she loved Helium and her people too much, but her people and her father and grandfather would rather die than ask her to marry Sab Than.  @Phil is wrong, there's no indication of an old woman giving him a potion in the book.  Indications throughout the books are that he dies and, on death, goes to Mars.

Comment: @tangooversway read the book and my comment, i mentioned no potion. After John Carter returns to Earth he quite definitely describes an old woman "As i approached i saw that it was the dead and mummified remains of a little old woman with long black hair, and the thing it leaned over was a small charcoal burner upon which rested a round copper vessel containing a small quantity of greenish powder." Its perfectly clear for all to see that the gas that overcame John Carter was produced by the old lady and that the skeletons on rawhide rope she rattled were trying to scare away John Carter and th

Comment: @phil: I've read the book.  Read 'em all many, many times. The chapter where he leaves Earth is "The Escape of the Dead." He also refers to his "lifeless body."  On returning he finds the dead woman, but there's no evidence it had to do with his trip. (It could be she was what frightened the Indians.) It's possible she may have killed him with gas, but it's made clear in the series when he dies on one planet, he goes to the other. If she did anything, it was to kill him, not give him an out of body experience.  (That would be out of step with the rest of the series.)

Answer (score 6):

*If I may add to the all correct DannyBGood points:*
1. Zodanga wasn't a walking city
2. Dejah wasn't a "professor" (nor was she an archeologist)
3. Iss temple wasn't a high-tech planetarium
4. John Carter wasn't just a clumsy jumper who in the end got angry (they say in the first scenes he is a great soldier, apparently the humour of Disney-Barsoom causes him to forget all about war strategy and ethics)
*Despite all these inaccuracies, I enjoyed the movie. Don't forget Giacchino.*

Answer (score 3):

The first ten minutes of the movie were posted online somewhere. After watching that clip and reading the beginning of the book, the most obvious difference was in the character of John Carter himself.

In the book, he was a traditional *Southern Gentleman* - well educated, well spoken, and well mannered.

In the movie, he was an unkempt, drunken, disgruntled thug.

Answer (score 3):

In the book, John Carter is of mysterious background. He doesn't remember his childhood, doesn't age, and only remembers being a warrior. The implication being that he's immortal. The Burroughs character is not a true nephew, but rather John Carter is a close friend of his family as a child.

Carter travels to Mars via astral projection. He actually walks around on Earth briefly and knows he is going to Mars as he is gazing at it and flies toward it at incredible speed.

The Tharks have no sense of compassion whatsoever. They find humor in violence, even of their own kind. The Red Men are not much better.
They do not kill their own eggs after the hatching.
They are a little larger than depicted in the film, and are hugely muscular - including the women, not the skinny things depicted in the movie.
Tars Tarkus is a mighty warrior chief (a Jed), not a weakling dependent on out-thinking his opponents, but he is very intelligent as well. He is one of many minor chiefs and there is a capital city, several days journey away, to which he brings Carter to participate in the arena - which is ruled by a fat lazy and vicious king (Jeddak)
The "milk" is from a plant and becomes Carter's chief source of nutrition and water.
The Therns are bald but they wear yellow wigs in shame. They don't make an appearance at all in the first book and there is not visit to the Gates of Iss in the first book. When Carter does go in the second book, he finds the White Men (Therns) are not supernatural (as is believed by the Red and Green men) or technologically advanced, but that they are religious fanatics deluded into thinking themselves gods.
The Temple of Issus (in the second book) is inhabited by the Black men of Mars (but not black in the same sense of the Earth races, their skin is metallic or stone-like, and reflective).
There's pieces of the first two books scatter. Kantos Kan (played by James Purefoy) is in the second book. There's a crisis at the end of the first book to save Mars that is not in the movie, but some hints to it are, such as the racing little flier.

My favorite element of the book however is the florid language. It's beautiful how they speak, almost poetic. Other movies have embraced the creative use of speech with success. It could never be copied exactly (in some instances the sheer quantity of words spoken doesn't fit whatsoever with the fighting taking place simultaneously.. like a half of a page of intense intellectual conversation during just a few sword strokes..) but at least a nod would be fitting.

Barsoomians have the capability to remote view other planets and are familiar with Earth's inhabitants and culture.

And there's the matter of everyone on Mars being completely naked all the time

Answer (score 0):

They had to take a lot of liberties to turn this story into a good movie. The characters had absolutely no depth in any of the books. It was good guys vs bad guys and one chick that kept going back and forth between evil and good and you couldn't be sure about her. But the good guys were pretty much all like all the other good guys and the bad guys were all pretty much all the same too. All the ladies were there to look pretty and be rescued an they all immediately fell in love with JC. They really had to stretch to make the characters interesting. I guess that is why they decided to give the Therns some super tech to spice it up and give JC a strong villain he otherwise would not have. Also, they had to make the movie more PG and PC. In the books everyone was basically naked except in cold climates. Dejah is portrayed as some irresistible sex goddess no man can resist. They had to tone that stuff down, there is a lot of sexist stuff and racist stuff in these books because they were written around WWI time. Finally you have to do some stuff, like drink a potion to know the Barsoomian language in order to save time. This an expensive movie. Time matters.

Comment: Hi and welcome.. I would like to know where all this come from or is it only your belief ?

Comment: @Rocket User28732 is just describing some of the issues of the books that are unfilmable for a family friendly movie. Though, I don't know that I'd go so far as to say that the characters had absolutely no depth in the books.